# How do I save a set of folium markers to a geojson?

Tags: python, geojson, marker, folium

I have the following folium markers and would like to save them to a geojson file in python.

```
neb1 = folium.Marker([nebraska[0]+1.73, nebraska[1]-3.46], icon = folium.Icon()).add_to(m)
neb2 = folium.Marker([nebraska[0]+2.73, nebraska[1]-3.46], icon = folium.Icon()).add_to(m)
neb3 = folium.Marker([nebraska[0]+2.73, nebraska[1]-5.46], icon = folium.Icon()).add_to(m)
neb4 = folium.Marker([nebraska[0]+4.73, nebraska[1]-3.46], icon = folium.Icon()).add_to(m)
neb5 = folium.Marker([nebraska[0]+4.73, nebraska[1]], icon = folium.Icon()).add_to(m)
neb5 = folium.Marker([nebraska[0]+1.73, nebraska[1]+3.2], icon = folium.Icon()).add_to(m)
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: In my limited experience, I don't think it's possible. By the way, what kind of use do you want to save it for?

Comment: I would like to have the geojson for use in a points plotting program that I will write.

Comment: I'm not sure what your points program looks like, but it might be a good idea to organize it into geopandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a GeoJSON file using the [geojson](https://pypi.org/project/geojson/) library.

Note folium.Marker() uses coordinates in latitude, longitude order and geojson Point() coordinates are in longitude, latitude order so remember to use the correct order.

```python
from geojson import Feature, Point, FeatureCollection, dumps

nebraska = [38.2, -98.5] # lat, lon

points = [
    Point((nebraska[1]-3.46, nebraska[0]+1.73)),
    Point((nebraska[1]-3.46, nebraska[0]+2.73)),
    Point((nebraska[1]-5.46, nebraska[0]+2.73)),
    Point((nebraska[1]-3.46, nebraska[0]+4.73)),
    Point((nebraska[1], nebraska[0]+4.73)),
    Point((nebraska[1]+3.2, nebraska[0]+1.73))
    ]

features = [Feature(geometry=p) for p in points]
feature_collection = FeatureCollection(features)
with open("out.geojson", "w") as fout:
    fout.write(dumps(feature_collection))
```

This outputs a GeoJSON file with this structure:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -101.96, 39.93
                ]
            },
            "properties": {}
        },
        ...
}
```

You can then load the GeoJSON file into a folium map using the folium.GeoJson() function.

The GeoJSON file displayed in a folium map looks like this:
[image: folium map showing GeoJSON points]